# Detecting ANY touch (not TapGesture) in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, selector, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I know that you can use a UITapDetector to detect any time the screen is tapped. But, is there a way to detect any time the screen is simply touched? Long, short, whatever, the finger doesn't even have to come up again, just any time the screen is touched at all, have something happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, implement UIResponder [`touchesBegan(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) and related methods. Now you are receiving the raw touches (not completely raw, since they are still associated with the hit-test view); and you can interpret or respond to them however you like. That's how you'd implement a drawing app, for example.

That in fact is what we *used* to have to do for *all* touches, before gesture recognizers were invented.

Comment: o awesome thanks, so if I had something like this: ~~~Swift class MyTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer{
    var number = 0
} ~~~ how would I reimplement it with a UIResponder?

Comment: I don't know what remake it means. You just override `touchesBegan` in your view and now (if it is user interactive) a touch of any sort triggers that method and you can do whatever you like. Example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch05p194touches/ch18p533touches/MyViews.swift